# How to map the values from ngForm

Tags: angular

```
getForm(formulaire: NgForm){
      formulaire.value.map(val => console.log(val))
    }
```

Actually I get the formulaire.value like this :

```
{
     '1' : '2',
     '2' : '4',
     '3' : '5',
     '4' : '3',
}
```

but I can't map it
I tried it to get each value from this but It said that formulaire.value.map is not a function

Comment: Use Object.keys or Object.values to convert array then transform uisng map

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
getForm (formulaire: NgForm) {
  Object.values(formulaire.controls).map((item) => {
    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks but actually that's not what I really want